# Why does my job get stuck in queue forever : 'Processing - "The printer is in use."'?

Tags: printing, cups

Why does my job get stuck in queue forever while the previous job got printed successfully ?

[CUPS](http://localhost:631/jobs/) says 'Processing - "The printer is in use."'

Here are a little more details :

```bash
$ ping -c3 LexmkMS310dn.lan 
PING LexmkMS310dn.lan (192.168.2.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from LexmkMS310dn.lan (192.168.2.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=5.95 ms
64 bytes from LexmkMS310dn.lan (192.168.2.3): icmp_seq=2 ttl=254 time=5.88 ms
64 bytes from LexmkMS310dn.lan (192.168.2.3): icmp_seq=3 ttl=254 time=5.33 ms

--- LexmkMS310dn.lan ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.335/5.727/5.959/0.285 ms
$ lpstat -d
system default destination: LexmkMS310dn
$ lpr -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.pdf 
$ lpq -a +3
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
Rank    Owner   Job     File(s)                         Total Size
active  sebasti 634     carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.p 62464 bytes
^C
$ pdfinfo carine-ordre-chronoboucled_or.pdf 
Title:          les 3 ourschronologie de l'histoire
Subject:        
Keywords:       
Author:         Sylvaine
Creator:        PDFCreator Version 0.9.9
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 8.70
CreationDate:   Mon Feb  7 16:42:54 2011
ModDate:        Mon Feb  7 16:42:54 2011
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          3
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       90
File size:      61769 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

Here are some CUPS logs :

```bash
$ tail /var/log/cups/{access,error,page}_log
==> /var/log/cups/access_log <==
localhost - sebastien [18/Mar/2020:21:47:51 +0100] "GET /admin/log/error_log? HTTP/1.1" 200 23345 - -
localhost - sebastien [18/Mar/2020:21:48:55 +0100] "GET /admin/log/access_log? HTTP/1.1" 200 19898 - -
localhost - - [18/Mar/2020:21:50:15 +0100] "POST /printers/LexmkMS310dn HTTP/1.1" 200 466 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [18/Mar/2020:21:50:15 +0100] "POST /printers/LexmkMS310dn HTTP/1.1" 200 38240 Send-Document successful-ok
localhost - sebastien [18/Mar/2020:21:51:12 +0100] "GET /admin/log/page_log? HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - -
localhost - sebastien [18/Mar/2020:21:51:20 +0100] "GET /admin/log/access_log? HTTP/1.1" 200 20333 - -
localhost - sebastien [18/Mar/2020:21:51:40 +0100] "GET /admin/log/error_log? HTTP/1.1" 304 0 - -
localhost - - [18/Mar/2020:21:51:57 +0100] "POST /jobs/ HTTP/1.1" 200 178 Cancel-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [18/Mar/2020:21:52:13 +0100] "POST /printers/LexmkMS310dn HTTP/1.1" 200 466 Create-Job successful-ok
localhost - - [18/Mar/2020:21:52:13 +0100] "POST /printers/LexmkMS310dn HTTP/1.1" 200 38240 Send-Document successful-ok

==> /var/log/cups/error_log <==
W [18/Mar/2020:21:41:35 +0100] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'EPSON_XP-312-RGB..' already exists
E [18/Mar/2020:21:43:57 +0100] [Client 17] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [18/Mar/2020:21:43:59 +0100] [Client 17] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [18/Mar/2020:21:44:38 +0100] [Client 17] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [18/Mar/2020:21:44:49 +0100] [Client 16] pam_authenticate() returned 7 (Authentication failure)
E [18/Mar/2020:21:46:40 +0100] [Client 17] Request for non-absolute resource "".
E [18/Mar/2020:21:46:40 +0100] [Client 17] Request for non-absolute resource "".
W [18/Mar/2020:21:46:40 +0100] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LexmkMS310dn-Gray..' already exists
E [18/Mar/2020:21:47:07 +0100] [Client 17] Request for non-absolute resource "".
W [18/Mar/2020:21:47:07 +0100] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'LexmkMS310dn-Gray..' already exists

==> /var/log/cups/page_log <==
```

Retried with another document and still the same pb. :

```bash
$ lprm
$ lpstat -l
LexmkMS310dn-641        sebastien        38912   mer. 18 mars 2020 22:27:42 CET
    Status: The printer is in use.
    Alerts: job-printing
    queued for LexmkMS310dn
$ lpstat -l -p LexmkMS310dn
printer LexmkMS310dn now printing LexmkMS310dn-641.  enabled since mer. 18 mars 2020 23:10:05 CET
    The printer is in use.
    Form mounted:
    Content types: any
    Printer types: unknown
    Description: Lexmark MS310dn
    Alerts: toner-empty-warning
    Location: 
    Connection: direct
    Interface: /etc/cups/ppd/LexmkMS310dn.ppd
    On fault: no alert
    After fault: continue
    Users allowed:
        (all)
    Forms allowed:
        (none)
    Banner required
    Charset sets:
        (none)
    Default pitch:
    Default page size:
    Default port settings:
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer below :

```bash
$ lpstat -l -p LexmkMS310dn | grep Alerts:
    Alerts: toner-empty-warning
```

and the [LexmarkMS310dn webinterface](http://lexmkms310dn.lan./cgi-bin/dynamic/printer/PrinterStatus.html) says :

```bash
Cartridge Status: Black Cartridge

     Replace, 0 estimated pages remain
```